# Error when trying to add a row to an already existing data table and grid view

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2017

I currently have a gridview that I am able to populate with a query. On a button click I would like to run the query again with a new value and add the new information to what is already displayed in the gridview. I am attempting to do this by copying the information that is currently in the gridview into a datatable then adding a row to the table then resetting the binding on the gridview and refreshing the gridview. The problem is I get an error when trying to add the new row (System.Data.NoNullAllowedException: 'ColumnName' does not allow nulls.

Here is the code I am trying to use for this process. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Dim EpicorCM As New SqlCommand(JobSelect, EpicorCon)
            EpicorCon.Open()
            Dim EpicorReader As SqlDataReader = EpicorCM.ExecuteReader
            Dim JobInfoTable As New DataTable
            JobInfoTable = CType(dgvJobInfo.DataSource, DataTable).Copy
            JobInfoTable.Rows.Add(EpicorReader)
            dgvJobInfo.AutoGenerateColumns = True
            dgvJobInfo.DataSource = JobInfoTable
            dgvJobInfo.Refresh()
            EpicorCon.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a `SqlDataReader` to the `Rows` collection but that will not work. It only compiles because the `Add()` method has an overload that is `params` of `Object`.

Fortunately `DataTable` has a method to load a reader. Instead of this:`JobInfoTable.Rows.Add(EpicorReader)`, do this:

```
JobInfoTable.Load(EpicorReader)
```

As an aside, commands and readers are Disposable resources so you can leak memory by not disposing of them either in `Using` blocks or in `Finally` blocks.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly.For some reason I thought using the .Load method would override the information already in the table.